# What is the difference between .mbin and .bin?

Tags: binary-files

I got a `.mbin` file this morning. As a newbie and just out of curiosity, is there any difference between `.mbin` and `.bin`?

If no, is that OK to swap `.mbin` with `.bin` in file name?

If yes, what are the commonly used binary file extensions? Where can I find references?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the .mbin file used for? From what I know is that it might be a proprietary binary format. By reading the file header you might be able to determine the actual file type. In Linux you can use the command 'file' for this.

Comment: Simply google 'mbin' it tells you it is a Mac Binary - takes just a second to do.

Comment: @Jeroen-ITNerdbox I encountered .mbin extension in the embedded system that I'm currently working on. The kernel is similar to Linux, and we use .mbin file to update the kernel rev. The motivation for this question is that, we have a routine to update another device with .bin extension. We  were just wondering if we can reuse that routine.            Thanks to your hint, Linux returns "data" with "file *.mbin".

Comment: Perhaps slightly off topic but what if you use binwalk on both the .mbin and .bin files? If the output is the same, I guess your routine can be used on the .mbin file as well.